# error in ngController (angularJS)

Tags: angularjs, ng-controller

I am getting error called

> Argument 'myController' is not a function, got undefined

Here is my Code:

**Script**

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);
        app.service("serviceText", function () {
            this.start = function (text) {
                return "service is started, Text is " + text;
            };
            this.end = function (text) {
                return "service is stopped, Text is " + text;
            };
        });
        function myController($scope,serviceText) {
            $scope.call = function () {
                $scope.msg = serviceText.start($scope.txt);
            }
            $scope.stop = function () {
                $scope.msg = serviceText.end($scope.txt);
            }
        }
```

**Html**

```
<body ng-app="app" >
    <div ng-controller="myController">
        <input type="text" name="name" ng-model="txt" />
        <button ng-click="call()" >Start</button>
        <button ng-click="stop()" >Stop</button>
        <br />
        <div>{{msg}}</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Please tell me whats wrong in my code

Comment: You have to define controller in app variable like:
app.controller('myController', function($scope, serviceText){...
});

Comment: ya i know that .. but some people were writing code using controller name as function name.. so i have written in same way .. but i am getting errror...

Comment: Refer this link for more details, you can find here to define controller as function along with requirejs :
https://github.com/parvsach/Angular-App-With-RequireJs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using angular version above 1.3, you should declare the controller like this,

```
app.controller('myController', function($scope, serviceText){ 

});
```

if your angular version is below 1.3 , you should call the controller,

```
app.controller('myController', myController)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add `app.controller('myController', myController)` before your controller function defination

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell `AngularJS` which `function` is the `controller`

Add this line

```
app.controller("myController",myController);
```

Your code should look like this

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);
        app.service("serviceText", function () {
            this.start = function (text) {
                return "service is started, Text is " + text;
            };
            this.end = function (text) {
                return "service is stopped, Text is " + text;
            };
        });

        app.controller("myController",myController);

        function myController($scope,serviceText) {
            $scope.call = function () {
                $scope.msg = serviceText.start($scope.txt);
            }
            $scope.stop = function () {
                $scope.msg = serviceText.end($scope.txt);
            }
        }
```

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/Kunalh/Ldhw9rgz/3/)

Answer (score 0):

```
You must have to add the controller's constructor function to the module using the .controller() like

var app = angular.module("app", []);
app.controller('myController',myController )
        app.service("serviceText", function () {
            this.start = function (text) {
                return "service is started, Text is " + text;
            };
            this.end = function (text) {
                return "service is stopped, Text is " + text;
            };
        });
        function myController($scope,serviceText) {
            $scope.call = function () {
                $scope.msg = serviceText.start($scope.txt);
            }
            $scope.stop = function () {
                $scope.msg = serviceText.end($scope.txt);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// create your main module
angular.module('myModule', []);

// create a service on this module
angular.module('myModule').factory('xxxService', xxxService);

   xxxService.$inject = ['$q', 'httpService'];

   function xxxService($q, httpService) {

      var service = {
         x: x
      };

   return service;

   function x() {

   }  
}
// create a controller on this module
angular.module('myModule').controller('XXXController', XXXController);

   XXXController.$inject = [];

   function XXXController() {
      var vm = this;

      activate();

      function activate() {

      }
   }
```